# No me reconoce el rect.center de una grupo de sprites (del sprite.Group) en PyGame (Python)

Tags: python, pygame

lo que trato de hacer es que una bala del enemigo salga de su cuerpo en mi videojuego. Lo que intento hacer es reposicionar la bala en el centro del rect generado en las imágenes de los enemigos pero estos ya están en un grupo de sprites. (sprite.Group)
Aquí:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Disparo_En(Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, a_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = a_game.screen
        self.juego = a_game
        self.color = a_game.colorbala
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Imagenes/balitauwu.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = a_game.enemys.center
```

Despues esto es lo que añadira el disparo a la ventana:
(esto esta en el while que ejecuta todo el juego)

```
    if self.velocidad_enemiga == 0:
       ahora = pygame.time.get_ticks()
       if ahora - self.ultimo_disparo > self.cadencia_enemiga:
             self.disparo_enemigo()

    if self.velocidad_enemiga_d == 0:
       ahora = pygame.time.get_ticks()
       if ahora - self.ultimo_disparo > self.cadencia_enemiga:
             self.disparo_enemigo()
```

Esta es la funcion de "disparo_enemigo":

```
def disparo_enemigo(self):
       bala = Disparo_En(self)
       self.balas_enemigas.add(bala)
```

Y ahora este es el class de los enemigos (donde se modifica su posición, se añade la imagen, el rect, etc...)

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class enemys(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, a_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = a_game.screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Imagenes/Enemychikito_de.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = -100
        self.rect.y = 400

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.juego = a_game

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.juego.velocidad_enemiga)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def checa_bordes(self):
        if self.rect.right >= self.juego.limite_Z:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("Imagenes/Enemychikito2.png").convert_alpha()
            return True
```

Y por ultimo este es el Error que me sale al ejecutarlo:
(psdta: el 'Terminator' es un class del archivo principal del videojuego)

```
File " ", line 12, in __init__
    self.rect.center = a_game.enemys.center
AttributeError: 'Terminator' object has no attribute 'enemys'
```

ESTE  es el Class "Terminator".

```
class Terminator():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Terminator X")
        self.color= (230,230,230) #(Rojo,Verde,Azul)
        self.score = 0
        self.contador_enemigos = 0
        self.cadencia_enemiga = 750
        self.ultimo_disparo = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.velocidad = 25
        self.anchobala = 1
        self.altobala = 1
        self.colorbala = (0, 0, 0)
        self.cantidad_balas = 20
        self.vida = 5
        self.escudo = 0
        self.estadisticas = Estadisticas(self)
        self.tablaP= TablaPuntajes(self)
        self.Sarah = Sarah(self)
        self.balas_restantes_Sarah = C_Balas(self)
        self.disparo_enem = Disparo_En(self)
        self.Enemigo_z = enemys(self)
        self.Enemigo_d = enemys_d(self)
        

        self.WIDTH = 1280
        self.HEIGHT = 720
        self.BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        self.WHITE=(255,255,255)
        self.ancho = 800
        
        pygame.mixer.music.load("Música/Musica de fondo.wav")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        #pygame.mixer.music.set_volume()

        self.enemys= pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemys_d= pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.velocidad_enemiga = 8.0
        self.velocidad_enemiga_d = 8.0
        self.flota_direccion = 1

        self.hitbox = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.escudo_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.balas_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.barricada = pygame.image.load("Imagenes/barricada.png").convert()
        self.barricada = pygame.transform.scale(self.barricada,(1282,120))
        self.barricada.set_colorkey(self.WHITE)
        self._create_fleet()
        self._create_fleet_d()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.background = pygame.image.load("Imagenes/fondo.png").convert()

        self.balas = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.balas_enemigas = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.juego_activado = False
        self.play_boton = Boton(self,"Play")

    def correr_game(self):
        while True:
            self.clock.tick(165)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.Sarah.mover_derecha = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.Sarah.mover_izquierda = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.Sarah.mover_arriba = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.Sarah.mover_abajo = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self._disparop_()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.Sarah.mover_derecha = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.Sarah.mover_izquierda = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.Sarah.mover_arriba = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.Sarah.mover_abajo = False
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    self.checaBoton(mousePos)

            if not self.juego_activado:
                    self.play_boton.dibujaBoton()

            if self.juego_activado:
                for bullet in self.balas.copy():
                    if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                        self.balas.remove(bullet)
                for bullet in self.balas.sprites():
                    bullet.draw_disparo()
                
                if self.velocidad_enemiga == 0:
                    ahora = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    if ahora - self.ultimo_disparo > self.cadencia_enemiga:
                        self.disparo_enemigo()

                if self.velocidad_enemiga_d == 0:
                    ahora = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    if ahora - self.ultimo_disparo > self.cadencia_enemiga:
                        self.disparo_enemigo()
                for bullet in self.balas_enemigas.sprites():
                    bullet.draw_disparo()

                self.enemys.draw(self.screen)
                self.enemys_d.draw(self.screen)
                
                


                self.tablaP.muestra_score()
                self.balas_restantes_Sarah.Muestra_balas()

                self.verificadorescudo = random.randrange(1, 340)
                self.verificadorbalas = random.randrange(1,140)
                if self.verificadorescudo  == 5:
                    self.escudoimg = AYU_ESCUDO(self)
                    self.all_sprites.add(self.escudoimg)
                    self.escudo_list.add(self.escudoimg)
                if self.verificadorbalas == 3:
                    self.municionimg= AYU_BALAS(self)
                    self.all_sprites.add(self.municionimg)
                    self.balas_list.add(self.municionimg)

                self.screen.blit(self.barricada, [0, 500])
                aliados_display(self.aliados_rect)
                aliados_display1(self.aliados1_rect)

                self.all_sprites.update()
                self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
                
                self.Sarah.mover()
                self.Sarah.corre()

                for hit in self.hitbox.sprites():
                    hit.draw_hitbox()
                
                self.balas.update()

                if self.contador_enemigos < 25:
                    self.update_enemiga()

                
            
            pygame.display.flip()


Por favor ayudenme!! no se que hacer.
```

Comment: Pues el error **no** proviene de intentar asignar un valor a self.rect.center. Proviene de intentar obtener el atributo enemys de a_game. En particular esta es la parte que falla: a_game.enemys.center. Podrías agregar tu clase Terminator por favor?

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue ya puedes ver la publicación nuevamente ya que lo acabo de editar.

Comment: Al instanciar a Disparo_En, intentas acceder al atributo enemys ANTES de crearlo. La solución: primero crea el atributo enemys y luego instancia a Disparo_En.

Comment: Es decir, estás creando una instancia de Disparo_En (que accede al atributo enemys durante su inicialización) lineas antes de crear el atributo enemys. Me explico?

Comment: Vale, ahora me sale: self.rect.center = a_game.enemys.center
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'center'

perdona, era self.rect.center = a_game.enemys.rect.center (me sale que no reconoce el rect, asi que de todas formas es el mismo error)

Comment: Las instancias de pygame.sprite.Group no tienen el atributo center. Que intentabas hacer en esa linea?

Comment: Como dije, intento que las balas aparezcan desde el centro de los enemigos.
@DanteS.

Comment: Perdón, no había notado que lo habías mencionado en la pregunta. En fin, ese atributo no existe. Tengo una idea: y si haces que Disparo_En reciba un segundo argumento que sea el enemigo desde el cual debe venir la bala y obtienes el centro de su rect, cambiando la linea que da error por self.rect.center = enemy.rect.center?

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias, ya no me sale el error pero ahora tengo otro problema, no me dibuja una bala, ahi tienes el class, me dices en que falla? o que te puedo mostrar más?

Comment: Buen día, es importante mantener una sola pregunta por publicación, por favor crea una nueva pregunta con el código actualizado y lo que has intentado hacer para solucionarlo

Comment: @HeytalePazguato vale, lo siento, ya agregue otra pregunta, me podrías ayudar por favor?

Comment: Bonus: no necesitas recorrer un grupo dibujando cada sprite. Si siempre creas un metodo draw que se encargue de dibujar el sprite, podes hacer "elgrupo.draw()" y pygame se encargara del trabajo de dibujar cada sprite c: y de nada nwn